# dynamic context menus

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenu

I'm trying to come up with a solution to create dynamic context menus that can be generated at run time.  I have implemented a `IGuiCommand` interface that implements something similar to the normal Command pattern.

```
interface IGuiCommand
{
    Execute();
    Undo();
    bool CanUndo {get;set;}
    Redo();
    string CommandName {get;set;}
    string CommandDescription {get;set;}
}
```

The idea is to allow the control that is Right Clicked to submit it's own list of commands to display in a given context menu.

While I could have each control build a context menu, I would prefer to use a single context menu and dynamicly generate the menu to allow easier management during run time. When a control state or application state changes, I would like the context menu to reflect the change. For example if I right click a checkbox, then the checkbox would submit to the context menu an Enable or Disable command to display depending on the checkbox's current Checked value.

I think I could easily implement this if I had some way to know which control was "Right Clicked" in order to bring up the context menu for that specific control.

It seems surprising the `ContextMenu` events doesn't supply an `EventArg` that indicates the control that was right clicked (or whatever command that would cause the context menu to Popup)

Comment: haha yeah i just realized i didn't add that info. It's WinForms  I'll add the tag

Comment: This must be a difficult question for WinForms.  But if anyone has an answer on how it would be done for WPF I'm all ears.  I'm just now redoing my GUI to a small utility so I could do it in WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to override the ContextMenuStrip_Opening event. The sender object is a ContextMenuStrip, which contains a SourceControl element. When you apply the proper cast, you will have access to everything you need.

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {
  var contextMenu = (sender as ContextMenuStrip);
  if (contextMenu != null) {
    var sourceControl = contextMenu.SourceControl;
    contextMenuStrip1.Items.Clear();
    //contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: Indeed as I was looking around I found that I had been trying to use the old ContextMenu rather than ContextMenuStrip.  All of the functionality I need is in the new ContextMenuStrip control.  Thanks for the response.